# Spark Script for Hadoop EC2 Installation: IPC client connection refused

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I was trying to use distcp to copy between Hadoop and Amazon S3 on a EC2 cluster setup by the spark scripts for EC2

```
[root]# bin/hadoop distcp s3n://bucket/f1 hdfs:///user/root/
```

The error I got was

```
INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: .. Already tried n time(s).

Copy failed: java.net.ConnectException: Call to ..my_server failed on connection excep\
tion: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Comment: why r u using hdfs:///user/root , is there other ways?

Comment: @member555: sorry, it's been a long time. I don't remember.

Answer (score 5):

Spark EC2 scripts, perhaps intentionally, do not start JobTracker and TaskTracker services.
So after running the Spark EC2 installation scripts, to start the services, I ran

```
{HADOOP_HOME}/bin/start-all.sh
```

Reference: Thanks Brock Noland at https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/H6wAfdeLIJo